# Unable to connect LocalDB from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, database-connection, visual-studio-2019

I had recently installed Visual Studio 2019. I wanted to add a database connection in VS but unfortunately, the VS does not detect the default instance of LocalDB, which I assume comes out of the box when installing VS (as it used to come with earlier version of VS).

I was trying to use the localdb to work with entity framework. I had no issue with VisualStuio 2017 but with new installation I cannot list out the localdb instance in database connection window.

I tried running the command **SQLLOCALDB INFO** in command line, where I got **MSSQLLOCALDB** as a result. I even tried running the command **SQLLOCALDB START MSSQLLOCALDB**. After execution of the command, I get the result that "**LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB**" started.". However, I am still not able to list/connect it via VS (Tools>>Connect to database).

[image]

Is there any additional steps specific to VS2019 that I need to follow in order to establish the connection with LocalDB or do I need to explicitly install the express version of MSSQL server.

Comment: LocalDB isn't Express. Are you trying to use Express or LocalDB here? Express, also, does not come with Visual Studio, it is an entirely separate installation; Express is not part of Visual Studio and never has been.

Comment: I meant to say localdb.

Comment: You should [edit] your question then to actually be representative of what you're trying to achieve then./

Comment: Have you tried connection manually to "(localdb)\mssqllocaldb" ?

Comment: Please note that the server closes down after some time without use, so make sure to check if it's still alive with: `.\SqlLocalDB.exe info "MSSQLLocalDB"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
(localdb)\MMSQLLocalDB
```

also

```
(localdb)\ProjectsV13
```